# Why is WPF ComboBox item not updating?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, combobox, selecteditem

I am not understanding why in my following example the "Billing Model" combobox doesn't display the property BillingModel.BillingModelDescription when the textbox does.  After selection of a client, i want the combobox to display the current billng model description, but it stays blank.  The textbox bound to the same thing does show the description.  I have a collection of possible models as the ItemsSource, which is working fine.  How do i update the Billing Model combobox upon selection of a client?

Here's the XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication7.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Label Content="Client"/>
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding AllClientData}" DisplayMemberPath="EmployerStr"
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedClient}"
              Width="300"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Label Content="Billing Model:"/>
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding AllBillingModels}" DisplayMemberPath="BillingModelDescription"
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedClient.BillingModel}"
              Width="300"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Label Content="Billing Model" />
    <TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedClient.BillingModel.BillingModelDescription}" Width="200"/>
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

And the code-behind (this is just an example, I am using MVVM etc in the full app, but this serves my puurpose to illustrate the issue):

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        AllClientData = new ObservableCollection<ClientRate>();
        AllBillingModels = new ObservableCollection<BillingModelType>();

        ClientRate uno = new ClientRate();
        uno.BillingModel = new BillingModelType();
        uno.BillingModel.BillingModelID = 3;
        uno.BillingModel.BillingModelDescription = "Free";
        uno.ID = 01;
        uno.EmployerName = "Employer1";

        ClientRate dos = new ClientRate();
        dos.BillingModel = new BillingModelType();
        dos.BillingModel.BillingModelID = 2;
        dos.BillingModel.BillingModelDescription = "Variable";
        dos.ID = 02;
        dos.EmployerName = "Employer2";

        ClientRate tre = new ClientRate();
        tre.BillingModel = new BillingModelType();
        tre.BillingModel.BillingModelID = 1;
        tre.BillingModel.BillingModelDescription = "Flat";
        tre.ID = 01;
        tre.EmployerName = "Employer3";

        AllClientData.Add(uno);
        AllClientData.Add(dos);
        AllClientData.Add(tre);

        BillingModelType one = new BillingModelType();
        one.BillingModelID = 1;
        one.BillingModelDescription = "Flat";

        BillingModelType two = new BillingModelType();
        two.BillingModelID = 2;
        two.BillingModelDescription = "Variable";

        BillingModelType three = new BillingModelType();
        three.BillingModelID = 3;
        three.BillingModelDescription = "Free";

        AllBillingModels.Add(one);
        AllBillingModels.Add(two);
        AllBillingModels.Add(three);

        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    private ObservableCollection<ClientRate> _allClientData;
    public ObservableCollection<ClientRate> AllClientData
    {
        get { return _allClientData; }
        set
        {
            if (_allClientData != value)
            {
                _allClientData = value;
                FirePropertyChanged("AllClientData");
            }
        }
    }

    private ClientRate _selectedClient;
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets/Sets Global SelectedClient object
    /// </summary>
    public ClientRate SelectedClient
    {
        get { return _selectedClient; }
        set
        {
            if (_selectedClient != value)
            {
                _selectedClient = value;
                FirePropertyChanged("SelectedClient");
            }
        }
    }

    //private BillingModelType _selectedBillingModel;
    //public BillingModelType SelectedBillingModel
    //{
    //    get
    //    {
    //        return _selectedBillingModel;
    //    }
    //    set
    //    {
    //        if (_selectedBillingModel != value)
    //        {
    //            _selectedBillingModel = value;
    //            FirePropertyChanged("SelectedBillingModel");
    //        }
    //    }
    //}

    private ObservableCollection<BillingModelType> _allBillingModels;
    /// <summary>
    /// Holds all possible billing model types 
    /// </summary>
    public ObservableCollection<BillingModelType> AllBillingModels
    {
        get { return _allBillingModels; }
        set
        {
            if (_allBillingModels != value)
            {
                _allBillingModels = value;
                FirePropertyChanged("AllBillingModels");
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void FirePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

    }
}

public class BillingModelType
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Billing Model ID
    /// </summary>
    public int? BillingModelID { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Billing Model Description
    /// </summary>
    public string BillingModelDescription { get; set; }
}

public class ClientRate : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Employer name with Employer ID in parentheses
    /// </summary>
    public string EmployerStr { get { return EmployerName + " (" + ID + ")"; } }
    /// <summary>
    /// Employer ID
    /// </summary>
    public int? ID { get; set; }
    private string _EmployerName;
    /// <summary>
    /// Employer Official Name
    /// </summary>
    public string EmployerName
    {
        get { return _EmployerName; }
        set
        {
            if (_EmployerName != value)
            {
                _EmployerName = value;
                FirePropertyChanged("EmployerName");
            }
        }
    }

    private BillingModelType _billingModel;
    /// <summary>
    /// Rate Type  ID and Description
    /// </summary>
    public BillingModelType BillingModel
    {
        get { return _billingModel; }
        set
        {
            if (_billingModel != value)
            {
                _billingModel = value;
                FirePropertyChanged("BillingModel");
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void FirePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

    }
}
```

Comment: one client has one billing mode? then why is it displayed as a selectable combo box? It can be a simple textbox that displays bound type of billing mode?

Comment: @Naresh it looks like you are expected to select the billing model for each client.

Comment: @amitfr then what does he mean by : "How do i update the Billing Model combobox upon selection of a client?". I guess, he has multiple billing modes, and a client can have a few of them as options? I am missing something?

Comment: yes, as you see i set the billing model for ie. Employer1 in code.  This should be displayed in the combobox.  But then i want to be able to select a different billing model if i want.

Comment: Basically, i want the combobox to show all possible BillingModel descriptions, and select the description that is currently assigned to the SelectedClient, and then be able to change it to one of the other possible BillingModels (and its descriptiopn).  I think my problem is appearing because even though the ID and Description of the BillingModel i set in code is the same as one of the choices in ItemSource, it is not actually the same object?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I fixed this problem by overriding Equals() in my BillingModelType class.  The problem was, as I suspected, that the BillingModel was not the exact same instance of BillingModel used in the list of possible selections.  So I simply added:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null || !(obj is BillingModelType))
            return false;
        return ((BillingModelType)obj).BillingModelID == this.BillingModelID;
    }

public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return this.BillingModelID.GetHashCode();
    }
```

to the class for BillingModelTypes, and all is well.  Credit to [Rachel Lim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/302677/rachel), as i found her blog here about this problem:
http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/08/20/comboboxs-selecteditem-not-displaying/#comments

Comment: Rachel also suggests you can use SelectedValue and SelectedValuePath to set the SelectedItem by Value instead of by Item, but I didn't know how to use these correctly.  Can anyone tell me?

Comment: Hi Theo, to use `SelectedValue` and `SelectedValuePath`, you would first set the `SelectedValuePath` to a string equal to your Identifier of the item (in your case, `SelectedValuePath="BillingModelID"`), then you would bind the `SelectedValue` to the Id of the selected item (`SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedClient.BillingModelID}"`). To do this, you would probably have to change your `SelectedClient` model a bit, since I don't think it will work correctly to bind to `SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedClient.BillingModel.BillingModelID}"`. I could be wrong though, so it wouldn't hurt to try it.

Comment: Hi Rachel, but how to change SelectedClient to make all of this work?  As you stated, the SelectedValue is not working with either binding to SelectedClient.BillingModelID or SelectedClient.BillingModel.BillingModelID).  I guess I still dont' understand WHY this won't work as it exists.

Comment: You'll need to change `SelectedClient` so the `BillingModel` property is one that is compared by value, not by reference. If you switch it to the `Id` property (`int`), then it will compare by value instead of by reference, so item with an Id of 1 will be considered the same as any `BillingModel` with an `Id` of 1. You're correct in your answer here that it is comparing the `SelectedClient.BillingModel` by reference, and the exact instance of the item doesn't exist in your list of `AllBillingModels`.

Comment: If you don't want to change your `SelectedClient` object so it contains an `int BillingId` property, then your best bet would be to just override `.Equals()` like you have

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what did you expect to happen, but you add to `AllBillingModels` all of the billing models (`one` `two` `three`), and they are all shown in the combobox (Flat, variable and free)

**EDIT:**

OK, if you are still here, I've got a nice idea
For your ComboBox Xaml:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Label Content="Billing Model:"/>
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding AllBillingModels}" DisplayMemberPath="BillingModelDescription"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedClient.BillingModel}"
                  Text="{Binding SelectedClient.BillingModel.BillingModelDescription}"
          Width="300"/>
</StackPanel>
```

This updates the test in the combobox.

Comment: yes they are shown in the combobox, but I want the value that is assigned to, for example, Employer1 to be selected in the combobox when i select Employer1 in the above combobox.  When i select Emploer1, "Free" should be then selected in the combobx.  You see it is displayed in the textbox

Comment: @TheoTheSuperCat see my edited answer, I think it's prettier.

Comment: That worked for my example.  In my actual app, this solution doesn't seem to work though because I already have the Text bound to BillingModelDescription like this to show ellipses if the text is too long for the combobox:  <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"  Text="{Binding BillingModelDescription}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>

Comment: I'm hoping someone can figure out how to use the SelectedValue and SelectedValuePath to do this, that would seem to be the "best" way